# How to make condition where value count more than 10 in SQL Serveerr

Tags: sql-server, count

I got a problem to filter my database.. This is my table structure (not all values which also filtered by SQL command) :

```
SELECT vehicleID,PositionDate,Speedreport 
FROM [PositionData820901-D] 
WHERE vehicleID = 'LT130' 
     AND (PositionDate between '20120214 00:00:00.000' AND '20120215 00:00:00.000' ) 
     AND (Speedreport BETWEEN 'Idle' and 'Moving')
ORDER BY positiondate
```

Sample Data:

```
VehicleID   PositionDate                SpeedReport 
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:00:42.000      Moving 
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:01:42.000      Idle 
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:02:42.000      Moving 
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:03:42.000      Idle 
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:04:42.000      Idle 
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:05:42.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:06:42.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:07:41.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:08:41.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:09:41.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:10:41.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:11:41.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:12:41.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:13:40.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:14:40.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:15:40.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:16:40.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:17:40.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:18:40.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:19:39.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:20:39.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:21:39.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:22:39.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:23:39.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:24:39.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:25:38.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:26:38.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:27:38.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:28:38.000      Idle
  LT130      2012-02-14 10:29:38.000      Moving
```

Now I want to return rows that start and end with 'Idle' values which meet the condition = `count() > 10` but the `Idle` values also must be in sequential rows not between 'Moving' values or anything else.. My desired output :

```
VehicleID  PositionDate               SpeedReport
   LT130    2012-02-14 10:03:42.000     Idle
   LT130    2012-02-14 10:28:38.000     Idle
```

Sorry for long table and I try using `count(*) > 10` but didn't give the output I want. I hope anyone can help me and I'll appreciate your help thanks.

Comment: What you need is more specific than counts. You need streaks, i.e., counts of consecutive records. I answered another streak question recently -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476016/attending-streak-mysql-query -- and there are many others on SO.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: duly noted marc_s.. John Pick: I try your code but my SpeedReport column is not int datatype. How can I change it to varchar datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Googled for **grouping consecutive rows using ranking functions** and found [this](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/solution-to-the-t-sql-puzzle-grouping-consecutive-rows-with-a-common-element). Here's the code for your scenario:

```
;WITH groups AS 
(
SELECT VehicleID 
    , SpeedReport
    , PositionDate
    , row_number() OVER(ORDER BY PositionDate) 
       - row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY SpeedReport ORDER BY SpeedReport, PositionDate)
       AS groupid
FROM [PositionData820901-D]
WHERE vehicleID = 'LT130' 
   AND PositionDate between '20120214 00:00:00.000' AND '20120215 00:00:00.000' 
   AND Speedreport IN ('Idle', 'Moving')
)

SELECT VehicleID, SpeedReport, MIN(PositionDate) AS PositionDate
FROM groups
GROUP BY VehicleID, SpeedReport, groupid
HAVING COUNT(1) > 10
UNION
SELECT VehicleID, SpeedReport, MAX(PositionDate) AS PositionDate
FROM groups
GROUP BY VehicleID, SpeedReport, groupid
HAVING COUNT(1) > 10
ORDER BY PositionDate
```

Comment: Thanx for your help @Diego. Somehow my Query Explus give me error - 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name. :(

Comment: Oh, i am sorry about that. It works in SQL Server 2005 and later, and other DBMSs. I'll post another way to do it if I have time.

Comment: Owh i see. Yup Im using SQL Server 2000.. Anyway thanks @diego for your help and I'm looking forward for your other solution.